# Laravel PDF not downloaded - Laravel dompdf

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-dompdf

I am facing a problem where the PDF file not downloaded when button clicked as well. The response status is 200 but nothing happen. Already refer to docs on how to use the laravel-dompdf library. My code is like below

```
       $pdf = Pdf::loadView('pdf.summary-daily', ['lastData' => $lastData, 'today' => $today]);



    if ($request->download) {
        // dd($request->download);
        return $pdf->download('summarydaily.pdf');
    } else {
        return $pdf->stream('summarydaily.pdf');
    }
```

how i can fix this ?

Comment: Does `stream()` work with the same data set and view?

Comment: @haakym Yes stream method work fine... As it is use at reactjs frontend

Comment: can you check if the pdf is saved in the desired folder? If it's generated, is the file name `summarydaily.pdf` (as per your description). Also try using laravel's response()->download method mentioned in the docs.- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#file-downloads